# AdWhirl causes IllegalStateException

Tags: java, android, xml, adwhirl, illegalstateexception

I am trying to add AdWhirl to my app, but I decided to start out with a simple "HelloWorld" to make sure I know what I'm doing.  Sure enough, I don't... I got this code from [the AdWhirl Android SDK Setup page](https://www.adwhirl.com/doc/android/AdWhirlAndroidSDKSetup.html), but when I try to run it, I get this exception: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.` It occurs on the line `layout.addView(adWhirlLayout, layoutParams)` so I've tried to removeView() as the exception message suggests as well as removeAllViews() but still I get this error.

Below is the Java file:

```
package hello.adwhirl;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.adwhirl.AdWhirlLayout;
import com.adwhirl.AdWhirlLayout.AdWhirlInterface;
import com.adwhirl.AdWhirlManager;
import com.adwhirl.AdWhirlTargeting;

public class HelloAdWhirl extends Activity implements AdWhirlInterface {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        AdWhirlManager.setConfigExpireTimeout(1000 * 60 * 5);

        AdWhirlTargeting.setAge(23);
        AdWhirlTargeting.setGender(AdWhirlTargeting.Gender.MALE);
        AdWhirlTargeting.setKeywords("online games gaming");
        AdWhirlTargeting.setPostalCode("94123");
        AdWhirlTargeting.setTestMode(false);

        AdWhirlLayout adWhirlLayout = (AdWhirlLayout) findViewById(R.id.adwhirl_layout);

        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        int diWidth = 320;
        int diHeight = 52;
        int density = (int) getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

        adWhirlLayout.setAdWhirlInterface(this);
        adWhirlLayout.setMaxWidth((int) (diWidth * density));
        adWhirlLayout.setMaxHeight((int) (diHeight * density));

        layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        textView.setText("Below AdWhirlLayout");

        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_main);

        layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        layout.addView(adWhirlLayout, layoutParams);
        layout.addView(textView, layoutParams);
        layout.invalidate();
    }

    public void adWhirlGeneric() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Do stuff");
    }
}
```

This is my main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/layout_main">
<com.adwhirl.AdWhirlLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/adwhirl_layout"></com.adwhirl.AdWhirlLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and the error:

```
03-19 15:35:54.218: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3510): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-19 15:35:54.218: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3510): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{hello.adwhirl/hello.adwhirl.HelloAdWhirl}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
03-19 15:35:54.218: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3510):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2833)
03-19 15:35:54.218: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3510):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2854)
03-19 15:35:54.218: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3510):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:136)
03-19 15:35:54.218: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3510):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2179)
03-19 15:35:54.218: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3510):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-19 15:35:54.218: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3510):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
03-19 15:35:54.218: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3510):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5061)
03-19 15:35:54.218: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3510):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-19 15:35:54.218: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3510):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-19 15:35:54.218: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3510):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-19 15:35:54.218: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3510):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-19 15:35:54.218: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3510):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-19 15:35:54.218: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3510): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
03-19 15:35:54.218: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3510):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:1992)
03-19 15:35:54.218: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3510):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1887)
03-19 15:35:54.218: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3510):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1867)
03-19 15:35:54.218: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3510):     at hello.adwhirl.HelloAdWhirl.onCreate(HelloAdWhirl.java:50)
03-19 15:35:54.218: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3510):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1066)
03-19 15:35:54.218: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3510):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2797)
03-19 15:35:54.218: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3510):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: we need your stack trace and the culprit line highlighted.

Comment: How would I highlight the culprit line? I mentioned it in the beginning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your AdWhirlLayout is actually already defined in your XML, so there is no need for you to add it again (you can remove the `layout.addView(adWhirlLayout, layoutParams);` line. As long as you've set your `ADWHIRL_KEY` properly in your manifest file, this should work properly.

Comment: When I remove that line, it runs but nothing shows except the random text view they added that says "Below AdWhirlLayout."  I do have the adwhirl key in the manifest file.

Comment: I just looked at the logcat and realized it doesn't show because there are no ads in rotation.